# How to loop through IEnumerable of anonymous type in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am getting data from a SQL server in the form of a data table. I am grouping the data by VendorID and concatenate the row data if there are multiple values of the field. This code is given below and it works fine.

```vb
Dim dt As DataTable = GetVendorData()
Dim results = From p In dt.AsEnumerable()
              Group p By VendorID = p.Field(Of String)("VenID") Into g = Group
              Select New With {
                  Key .VendorID = VendorID,
                  Key .FundNumber = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("FundNumber")),
                  Key .Statefund = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("Statefund")),
                  Key .State = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("State"))
              }
```

I tried to loop through and get the individual field data as follows

```vb
For Each result As DataRow In results
    Dim x As String = result.Field(Of String)("FundNumber"))
Next
```

But I am getting the following error.

> System.InvalidCastException
>
> HResult=0x80004002
>
> Message=Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousType_1`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

Comment: You select `New With { ...` which is an anonymous type, not a DataRow as you say `For Each result As DataRow In results`

Comment: The result of your Linq isn't a Datarow any more, it's an Anonymous Type.  Does it help any if you just `For Each result in results`?

Comment: I have tried that also. However, it doesn't even compile. I am getting this error: ""result" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: @user466663 it's no different from your original code except with implicit typing. How is it not declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line at the top of the .vb file, which fixed the issue:

Option Infer On

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an anonymous type with

```vb
Select New With {
    Key .VendorID = VendorID,
    Key .FundNumber = ...
```

You should be able to use result as an anonymous type and access the created FundNumber field

```vb
For Each result In results
    Dim x As String = result.FundNumber
Next
```

By the way, the error message

> Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousType_1' ... to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

is quite clear

Comment: I have tried that also. However, it doesn't even compile. I am getting this error: ""result" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"